flattening a json file using jq
I would like to flatten a json file in order to meet the needs of a legacy program.  I would prefer to use jq for this as I know it is available to me.
I have a file something like this:
[
{
"field1":10,
"field2":20,
"msg":
  {
  "a":1,
  "b":2,
  "c":3
  }
}
]

For reasons, I need to pull the a and b fields from msg and flatten their names:
[
{
"field1":10,
"field2":20,
"msg.a":1,
"msg.b":2,
"msg":   # the entire msg structure is now optional; if it falls off that's ok
  {
  "a":1,
  "b":2,
  "c":3
  },
}, ...
]

How is the miracle accomplished?

Does this answer your question? Flatten nested JSON using jq

There is a close on this question. I just want to say that the answer below is far better than the one in the suggested thread.

This works fine with the example input:
map(. + (.msg | {"msg.a": .a, "msg.b": .b}))

This is more flexible if the actual task involves more keys or keys with longer names:
map(. + (.msg | {a, b} | with_entries(.key |= "msg.\(.)")))

And if you do this for several fields like msg, a function could help shorten the code:
def f(x): . as $in
| reduce path(x) as $p ({};
  . + {($p | join(".")): $in | getpath($p)}
);
map(. + f(.msg | .a, .b))


You can delete the msg object using: map(del(.msg) + (.msg | {a, b} | with_entries(.key |= "msg.\(.)"))) and all fields: map(del(.msg) + (.msg | with_entries(.key |= "msg.\(.)"))) This works on https://www.jqkungfu.com/

Thank you, that's going to work.  But I have some reading to do.
